# Sentiment Analysis Datasets

Tags: data, sentiment-analysis

I am looking for sentiment analysis data, mostly customer product review.

I found a lot of research places provide large size of datasets, but many of them are outdated. I want to get more up-to-date data and I am willing to pay.

Is there any vendor that sells aggregated sentiment data from retailers or e-commerce. Or is there any other avenues we can get the review data.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Amazon Customer Review dataset which you can read more about [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon-reviews-pds/readme.html) - the data is stored in S3 and freely available for anyone to use.

It contains over 160 million customer reviews (the README suggests 130 million, but more data must have been added since that was written) made available by Amazon - you can access them in either TSV or Parquet format.

There is also a blog post on using this data set in sentiment analysis [here](https://kognitio.com/blog/sentiment-analysis-amazon-reviews-pt1/), which links to another post giving more technical detail. In summary, the blog looks at how sentiment correlates with the star rating in the reviews over time, across product categories, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the site! Most people in this scenario use either Yelp dataset and/or the IMDB dataset. The data is polarized enough for you to create sentiment analysis and be able to bootstrap a model from these initial sets to something customized to your particular need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking for aggregated product review data, say xbox review data from amazon, bestbuy, walmart. etc. Is there vendor sell this type of data that are up-to-date? Also can't buy that data from amazon? better include zipcode information

Comment: @user2979630 no I don’t know of a vendor. My posit is that type of data just gets scraped from the web and then used privately. Making that as a commercial product would most likely get you sued. So people just scrape it and use it and keep it quiet. My answer presented the only legal options I know of.